# Квоты в youtube api3

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

В одном гугл аккаунте, можно создавать много ключей api для парсинга ютуб.

Квота там, 1кк запросов в день.

Вопрос: Эта квота дается на все сгенерированные ключи в этом аккаунте или же на каждый ключ api будет 1кк запросов в день?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это вопрос к поддержке  youtube. Данный ресурс это не справочное бюро.

Answer (score 0):

На все ключи, но можешь создать несколько проектов, но если они все будут парсить для одного сайта то вскоре заблочат проекты. Лучше делать много акков, в каждом акке один проект и один ключ, вот тогда нормально. Сам мучаюсь =)